# How does Outer Space look like without a simplex?

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, free-groups, outer-automorphisms

Considering the simplicial structure of Culler and Vogtmanns Outer Space $CV_n$. The question is now:

> Let $\Delta \subset CV_n$ be a closed simplex of dimension $3n-4$ or $3n-5$, how does $CV_n \setminus \Delta$ look like?

For example in $CV_2$ if we take out a simplex corresponding to a theta-graph, we get six simply connected components, whereas if we take out a figure of eight we get three simply connected components. In other words we get a simply connected component for each adjacent maximal simplex.
This implies that if we have a path between to points which enters each simplex at most once (and stays away from the $3n-6$-skeleton) then the sequence of $3n-4$ and $3n-5$-simplices it hits is unique. Does something like this also hold for higher dimensions?

The question arose from the following construction: Starting with a closed simplex $\Delta_0$, is it possible to find a covering sequence of closed simplices $\Delta_i$ such that $\Delta_i$ and $\bigcup_{k<i} \Delta_k$ share exactly one face and $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb N} \Delta_i = CV_n$?

Comment: I think we need to be careful about what dimensions you’re asking for. $CV_n$ injects into a simplicial complex of dimension $3n-4$, so it contains no simplices, closed or otherwise, of dimension $3n-3$

Comment: @RyleeLyman: Yes sorry, that was a typo 3n-4-1 is of course 3n-5 not 3n-3. I fixed it.